Is there an R function for correcting an invalid line in a BayesX graph for logistic regression
I am trying to run a Bayesian Logistic regression model in r and I am getting the error from the logfile saying "the graph is invalid in line 3" I do not know how to fix the problem. If  there is a code in R to fix the error, please help. Here is my graph_file.gra:
210
56310001 5 56310013 56310082 56610050 56610367 56610672
56310003 5 56310013 56310075 56610597 56610612 56610752
56310011 5 56310013 56610047 56610050 56610352 56610367
56310013 5 56310013 56310084 56310086 56310110 56610130
56310014 4 56310013 56310018 56310107 56610781
56310018 5 56310013 56310014 56310084 56310107 56610781
56310024 5 56310013 56310084 56310086 56610130 56610389
56310073 5 56310013 56610597 56610612 56610684 56610754
56310074 5 56310013 56310078 56610409 56610410 56610597
56310075 5 56310013 56310003 56610597 56610684 56610752
56310078 5 56310013 56310074 56610409 56610410 56610597
56310082 5 56310013 56310001 56610367 56610621 56610672
56310084 5 56310013 56310024 56310086 56310110 56610389
56310086 5 56310013 56310024 56310084 56610130 56610389
56310107 5 56310013 56310014 56310018 56610766 56610781
56310110 4 56310013 56310084 56310086 56610130
56310112 5 56310013 56310001 56610225 56610352 56610672
56610008 5 56310013 56610011 56610013 56610024 56610033
56610011 5 56310013 56610013 56610033 56610365 56610366
56610013 5 56310013 56610011 56610033 56610365 56610366
56610014 5 56310013 56610011 56610013 56610016 56610029
56610016 5 56310013 56610011 56610013 56610014 56610018
56610018 5 56310013 56610014 56610016 56610029 56610372
56610020 5 56310013 56610188 56610375 56610382 56610619
56610024 5 56310013 56610008 56610033 56610034 56610366
56610029 5 56310013 56310011 56610014 56610047 56610354
56610033 5 56310013 56610013 56610034 56610365 56610366
56610034 5 56310013 56610013 56610033 56610365 56610366
56610043 5 56310013 56610047 56610354 56610359 56610362
56610047 5 56310013 56310011 56610043 56610050 56610362
56610050 5 56310013 56310011 56610047 56610352 56610367
56610094 5 56310013 56610095 56610185 56610188 56610241
56610095 5 56310013 56610094 56610185 56610188 56610500
56610100 5 56310013 56610106 56610113 56610251 56610363
56610106 5 56310013 56610192 56610533 56610534 56610535
56610113 5 56310013 56610115 56610118 56610533 56610534
56610115 5 56310013 56610113 56610118 56610533 56610534
56610118 5 56310013 56610113 56610115 56610533 56610534
56610124 5 56310013 56610169 56610173 56610605 56610607
56610127 5 56310013 56610277 56610278 56610285 56610540
56610130 4 56310013 56310084 56310086 56310110
56610134 5 56310013 56610138 56610286 56610537 56610614
56610138 5 56310013 56610134 56610286 56610288 56610289
56610148 5 56310013 56610149 56610152 56610307 56610667
56610149 5 56310013 56610148 56610614 56610615 56610616
56610152 5 56310013 56610148 56610307 56610667 56610669
56610156 5 56310013 56610162 56610163 56610168 56610605
56610162 5 56310013 56610156 56610163 56610168 56610169
56610163 5 56310013 56610156 56610162 56610164 56610168
56610164 5 56310013 56610163 56610168 56610667 56610669
56610168 5 56310013 56610156 56610162 56610163 56610164
56610169 5 56310013 56610124 56610162 56610163 56610605
56610173 5 56310013 56610124 56610169 56610235 56610607
56610177 5 56310013 56610124 56610173 56610235 56610758
56610185 5 56310013 56610094 56610095 56610266 56610500
56610188 5 56310013 56610020 56610241 56610372 56610375
56610192 5 56310013 56610106 56610200 56610533 56610535
56610197 5 56310013 56610201 56610586 56610587 56610593
56610199 5 56310013 56610200 56610204 56610208 56610585
56610200 5 56310013 56610106 56610192 56610199 56610535
56610201 5 56310013 56610197 56610586 56610587 56610615
56610204 5 56310013 56610199 56610200 56610266 56610500
56610208 5 56310013 56610212 56610585 56610589 56610593
56610212 5 56310013 56610208 56610217 56610585 56610589
56610217 5 56310013 56610208 56610212 56610589 56610599
56610221 5 56310013 56610217 56610223 56610654 56610675
56610223 5 56310013 56610217 56610221 56610276 56610675
56610225 4 56310013 56310110 56610130 56610388
56610235 5 56310013 56610124 56610173 56610276 56610751
56610237 5 56310013 56610238 56610686 56610751 56610759
56610238 5 56310013 56610237 56610686 56610751 56610759
56610241 5 56310013 56610020 56610094 56610188 56610372
56610251 5 56310013 56610113 56610254 56610260 56610261
56610253 5 56310013 56610398 56610399 56610402 56610531
56610254 5 56310013 56610251 56610260 56610261 56610269
56610260 5 56310013 56610261 56610265 56610268 56610269
56610261 5 56310013 56610260 56610265 56610268 56610269
56610265 5 56310013 56610260 56610261 56610268 56610269
56610266 5 56310013 56610185 56610199 56610204 56610500
56610268 5 56310013 56610260 56610261 56610265 56610269
56610269 5 56310013 56610260 56610261 56610265 56610274
56610274 5 56310013 56610261 56610269 56610277 56610540
56610276 5 56310013 56610173 56610235 56610238 56610751
56610277 5 56310013 56610274 56610278 56610285 56610540
56610278 5 56310013 56610127 56610277 56610285 56610286
56610279 5 56310013 56610277 56610282 56610283 56610548
56610282 5 56310013 56610279 56610283 56610548 56610552
56610283 5 56310013 56610279 56610282 56610552 56610555
56610285 5 56310013 56610127 56610277 56610278 56610286
56610286 5 56310013 56610285 56610288 56610289 56610295
56610288 5 56310013 56610286 56610289 56610294 56610295
56610289 5 56310013 56610286 56610288 56610294 56610295
56610291 5 56310013 56610288 56610289 56610294 56610295
56610294 5 56310013 56610288 56610289 56610291 56610295
56610295 5 56310013 56610288 56610289 56610291 56610294
56610296 5 56310013 56610553 56610561 56610567 56610628
56610300 5 56310013 56610291 56610294 56610295 56610307
56610304 5 56310013 56310086 56610130 56610225 56610388
56610306 5 56310013 56610300 56610307 56610309 56610567
56610307 5 56310013 56610152 56610300 56610306 56610309
56610309 5 56310013 56610300 56610306 56610307 56610567
56610316 5 56310013 56610306 56610309 56610572 56610575
56610334 5 56310013 56610164 56610168 56610316 56610669
56610352 5 56310013 56310011 56610047 56610050 56610362
56610353 5 56310013 56610034 56610043 56610365 56610366
56610354 5 56310013 56610029 56610043 56610365 56610366
56610359 5 56310013 56610043 56610047 56610352 56610362
56610362 5 56310013 56310011 56610047 56610050 56610352
56610363 5 56310013 56610106 56610113 56610533 56610534
56610365 5 56310013 56610013 56610033 56610034 56610366
56610366 5 56310013 56610013 56610033 56610034 56610365
56610367 5 56310013 56310001 56310011 56610050 56610352
56610372 5 56310013 56610020 56610241 56610620 56610621
56610375 5 56310013 56610020 56610382 56610385 56610619
56610382 5 56310013 56610375 56610385 56610619 56610679
56610385 5 56310013 56610382 56610619 56610654 56610679
56610388 5 56310013 56310086 56610130 56610225 56610304
56610389 5 56310013 56310024 56310084 56310086 56310110
56610391 5 56310013 56610268 56610392 56610393 56610396
56610392 5 56310013 56610391 56610393 56610394 56610396
56610393 5 56310013 56610268 56610391 56610392 56610396
56610394 5 56310013 56610253 56610396 56610399 56610531
56610396 5 56310013 56610392 56610393 56610394 56610399
56610398 5 56310013 56610253 56610399 56610402 56610531
56610399 5 56310013 56610253 56610398 56610402 56610404
56610402 5 56310013 56610253 56610398 56610399 56610404
56610404 5 56310013 56610398 56610399 56610402 56610406
56610406 5 56310013 56610404 56610408 56610515 56610519
56610408 5 56310013 56610406 56610413 56610515 56610522
56610409 5 56310013 56310074 56310075 56310078 56610410
56610410 5 56310013 56310074 56310078 56610409 56610597
56610412 5 56310013 56610600 56610604 56610605 56610606
56610413 5 56310013 56610408 56610424 56610521 56610522
56610423 5 56310013 56610551 56610553 56610561 56610628
56610424 5 56310013 56610425 56610427 56610521 56610522
56610425 5 56310013 56610423 56610424 56610427 56610521
56610427 5 56310013 56610424 56610425 56610434 56610521
56610434 5 56310013 56610425 56610427 56610572 56610575
56610500 5 56310013 56610185 56610188 56610204 56610266
56610505 5 56310013 56610508 56610525 56610528 56610529
56610508 5 56310013 56610525 56610528 56610529 56610531
56610515 5 56310013 56610406 56610408 56610519 56610522
56610519 5 56310013 56610402 56610406 56610408 56610515
56610521 5 56310013 56610413 56610424 56610427 56610522
56610522 5 56310013 56610408 56610413 56610424 56610521
56610525 5 56310013 56610508 56610528 56610529 56610531
56610528 5 56310013 56610505 56610508 56610525 56610529
56610529 5 56310013 56610508 56610525 56610528 56610531
56610531 5 56310013 56610253 56610398 56610508 56610529
56610533 5 56310013 56610106 56610118 56610534 56610535
56610534 5 56310013 56610118 56610533 56610535 56610536
56610535 5 56310013 56610106 56610533 56610534 56610536
56610536 5 56310013 56610534 56610535 56610537 56610538
56610537 5 56310013 56610134 56610535 56610536 56610538
56610538 5 56310013 56610534 56610535 56610536 56610537
56610540 5 56310013 56610118 56610127 56610274 56610277
56610548 5 56310013 56610282 56610283 56610552 56610555
56610551 5 56310013 56610553 56610555 56610559 56610561
56610552 5 56310013 56610282 56610283 56610548 56610555
56610553 5 56310013 56610551 56610559 56610561 56610628
56610555 5 56310013 56610551 56610552 56610553 56610559
56610559 5 56310013 56610551 56610553 56610555 56610561
56610561 5 56310013 56610423 56610551 56610553 56610628
56610567 5 56310013 56610296 56610306 56610309 56610628
56610572 5 56310013 56610561 56610567 56610575 56610628
56610575 5 56310013 56610561 56610567 56610572 56610628
56610585 5 56310013 56610197 56610208 56610589 56610593
56610586 5 56310013 56610197 56610201 56610587 56610615
56610587 5 56310013 56610197 56610586 56610615 56610616
56610589 5 56310013 56610197 56610208 56610585 56610593
56610593 5 56310013 56610197 56610585 56610589 56610599
56610597 5 56310013 56310003 56310075 56610684 56610752
56610599 5 56310013 56610412 56610589 56610593 56610600
56610600 5 56310013 56610412 56610599 56610604 56610606
56610604 5 56310013 56610412 56610600 56610605 56610606
56610605 5 56310013 56610412 56610604 56610606 56610607
56610606 5 56310013 56610412 56610604 56610605 56610607
56610607 5 56310013 56610124 56610412 56610605 56610606
56610612 5 56310013 56310073 56610597 56610682 56610684
56610614 5 56310013 56610149 56610587 56610615 56610616
56610615 5 56310013 56610197 56610586 56610587 56610616
56610616 5 56310013 56610149 56610587 56610614 56610615
56610619 5 56310013 56610375 56610382 56610385 56610679
56610620 5 56310013 56610372 56610382 56610619 56610621
56610621 5 56310013 56310082 56610372 56610382 56610620
56610627 5 56310013 56310082 56610672 56610688 56610766
56610628 5 56310013 56610296 56610423 56610553 56610561
56610654 5 56310013 56610221 56610223 56610385 56610675
56610667 5 56310013 56610152 56610164 56610307 56610669
56610669 5 56310013 56610152 56610164 56610168 56610667
56610672 5 56310013 56310001 56310082 56610367 56610627
56610675 5 56310013 56610221 56610223 56610385 56610654
56610677 5 56310013 56310003 56610612 56610682 56610683
56610679 5 56310013 56610382 56610385 56610619 56610677
56610681 5 56310013 56610612 56610682 56610683 56610685
56610682 5 56310013 56610612 56610681 56610683 56610684
56610683 5 56310013 56610677 56610681 56610682 56610685
56610684 5 56310013 56310073 56610597 56610612 56610682
56610685 5 56310013 56610681 56610682 56610683 56610686
56610686 5 56310013 56610237 56610238 56610685 56610759
56610688 5 56310013 56310003 56310075 56610677 56610752
56610751 5 56310013 56610237 56610238 56610758 56610759
56610752 5 56310013 56310003 56310075 56610597 56610612
56610754 5 56310013 56310073 56310078 56610612 56610684
56610758 5 56310013 56610751 56610759 56610761 56610762
56610759 5 56310013 56610751 56610758 56610761 56610762
56610761 5 56310013 56610751 56610758 56610759 56610762
56610762 5 56310013 56610751 56610758 56610759 56610761
56610766 5 56310013 56310014 56310018 56310107 56610627
56610781 5 56310013 56310014 56310018 56310084 56610389
I do have 210 Enumeration area codes. From line 2, the first column shows the EA codes, followed by number of neighbours and followed by neighbouring EAs.
I thougt there were some empty spaces between the entries and i tried to clean them but the error is still indicating that the graph is invalid in line 3

It is impossible to work out where your data columns are. It doesn't look at all minimal to me. If it fails on "line 3" then show us the first 5 or 10 lines not the entire file!
